# Python get and compare prices

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the latest bitcoin prices and compare the last price with the most recent and write out if the price has gone up or down.

I'm using WebSockets to stream the values in real time so I can get the latest price per second, and then I'm trying to take the value of the last stream and trying to compare it with the current.

The WebSocket returns this:

```
2021-04-10T14:53:57.297218Z                    60300.010                 BTC-USD    channel type:ticker
```

I've then passed the value `60300.010` into a var called `price_val` which I'd then like to compare with the next line?
When I try to do:

```
latest_val = price_val
   if latest_val < price_val
   print("down")
```

But I get  `local variable 'price_val' referenced before assignment`.

Probably a much better way to do this, but not sure how?

Here is the code I'm using to get the live prices

```
class TextWebsocketClient(cbpro.WebsocketClient):
    def on_open(self):
        self.url           = 'wss://ws-feed-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com'
        self.message_count = 0
    
    def on_message(self,msg):
        self.message_count += 1
        msg_type = msg.get('type',None)
        if msg_type == 'ticker':
            time_val   = msg.get('time',('-'*27))
            price_val  = msg.get('price',None)
            if price_val is not None:
                price_val = float(price_val)
            product_id = msg.get('product_id',None)
            outFile = open('sample.txt', 'a')
            outFile.write(f"{time_val:30} \
                {price_val:.3f} \
                {product_id}\tchannel type:{msg_type}\n")
            outFile.close()
            #print(f"{time_val:30} \
            #    {price_val:.3f} \
            #    {product_id}\tchannel type:{msg_type}")

    
    def on_close(self):
        print(f"<---Websocket connection closed--->\n\tTotal messages: {self.message_count}")
```

Within the `def on_message` I added the

```
latest_val = price_val
   if latest_val < price_val
   print("down")
```

but this doesn't seem to work as `latest_val` and `price_val` are now the same value.

Comment: Where's your `price_val` declaration? You didn't include the only line that matters.

Comment: The shown code is syntactically incorrect, is improperly indented and seems to be actually part of a function. You should just copy & paste an appropriate part of the real code.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain what actually happening.

1. You declare a local variable named `price_val`
2. You assign `price_val.val(...)` something like that  to `price_val` (Since you didn't give all of your code so I just guess it.)
3. But price_val is a local variable which doesn't have a value yet (unbound local)

That's why Your program crashs.

**To fix these issue :**

You can fix this by passing parameters rather than relying on Globals

For example , your code is :

```
Var1 = 1
Var2 = 0

def function(): 
    pass
```

You have to change it as like as below :

```
def function(Var1, Var2):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks Sayeed, I've been trying to get this working, but i can't figure it out. Could you show how i pass the price_val out of the class?